# Should I need to open port 25 for sending email using ses from ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, django-rest-framework, boto, amazon-ses

I'm using Amazon SES to send emails from ec2 instance to the app users, I've sent emails using the sandbox ses account. I want to move out of sandbox, I'm little bit confused after gone through the documents,

> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html
> https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-port-25-throttle/

I've sent the support mail to raise the daily limits,(I don't need to send much emails, only forgot password emails + welcome).

> Should I need to open port 25 on the ec2 instance? Should I need to
> create DNS A record?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: None of those documents even mention port 22 or A record?

Comment: The 2nd link mentioned about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, you do not need to open any ports** in AWS security group.

1) You need to send request to **raise your [AWS SES sending limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/limits.html)**

Sandbox limit is 1/sec, 200/day is very low, and 1/sec very easy to exceed without exceeding 200/day and if your app does not support retries = no email.

2) As far as you send email from ec2 instance - this means you are connecting to another email server.

Your ec2 instance -> SES (25 port)

Email servers listen on standard ports, 25 is most common smtp port to connect to send emails. Because it is most common - it presumably gets more spam, third-party services may block ip because of spam - and that's why amazon throttles traffic that is send to 25 port.

So, you also **need to remove [25 port throttle for your ec2 instance](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-port-25-throttle/) by filing a request**.

For this you also need valid domain name associated with your ec2 instance - dns A record. I.e. `mydomain.domain.com` pointing to your ec2 elasctic ip `22.22.22.22`. This is also to ensure you are a valid sender, not spam.
So, if emails are from `@mydomain.domain.com` domain - any mail server can tell email origin.

Things to consider:

- Your ec2 instance has elastic ip (or you can add one).
- you have your own domain name registered with some domain registrar, i.e. myowndomain.domain.com
- You can buy your own domain name from Route 53, other domain registrars
- Most registrars provide integrated DNS management (at least basic)
- you need to add dns A record pointing to your ec2 elastic ip

Answer (score 1):

To send email using SES, you need to verify sending domains or individual email address. verifying the domain is convenient because it will be a hazzle setting up each individual email address.

in regards to DNS record, yes you will need to add few dns entries to confirm your ownership.

in regards to opening port 22, you don't need to open port 22. But you will need to have outgoing ports 465 or 587 enabled because thats the ports used for SSL.

Yes, port 25 has throttling issues, you don't have that issue, if you use SSL to send out emails.